# How do I get the Uid of the current user and of other users from firebase realtime database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, sharedpreferences

I had user shared preferences to get the current Uid or other Uid from realtime database. But I need to do the same without the use of shared preferences. This is for my ProfileActivity and I am using viewpager with three different fragments. The shared preferences show only the current user's profile even when searched for other user in the app.

The image attached is the output of the profile activity in my smartphone. The top bar containing the username and the logout button is of the profile activity and the rest below the blue banner is of the viewpager

[image]

```
public class ProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


private ImageView logout;
private TextView post;
private FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton;
private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;
private TextView username;


private FirebaseUser fUser;
private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
private FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
String profileId;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

    fUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
            .child("Users").child(Objects.requireNonNull(firebaseAuth.getUid()));

    String data = getBaseContext().getSharedPreferences("PROFILE", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
            .getString("profileId", "none");

    if (data.equals("none")){
        profileId = fUser.getUid();
    } else{
        profileId = data;
    }

    logout = findViewById(R.id.log_out);
    username = findViewById(R.id.username);
    floatingActionButton = findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButton);
    post = findViewById(R.id.posts_account);
    tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    VPAdapter vpAdapter = new VPAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), FragmentPagerAdapter.BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT);
    vpAdapter.addFragment(new Profile(), "Profile");
    vpAdapter.addFragment(new MyPosts(), "Posts");

    if (profileId.equals(fUser.getUid())){
        vpAdapter.addFragment(new SavedPosts(), "Saved");
    }

    viewPager.setAdapter(vpAdapter);

    getPostCount();
    userInfo();

    getSupportActionBar().hide();

    floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(ProfileActivity.this, PostActivity.class));
            finish();
        }
    });

    logout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AlertDialog alertDialog =  new AlertDialog.Builder(ProfileActivity.this).create();
            alertDialog.setTitle("Are you sure to logout?");
            alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                    startActivity(new Intent(ProfileActivity.this, StartActivity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK));
                    finish();
                }
            });

            alertDialog.show();
            alertDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE)
                    .setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(ProfileActivity.this, R.color.colorRed));
            alertDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE)
                    .setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(ProfileActivity.this, R.color.colorRed));
        }
    });


}


private void getPostCount() {

    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Posts").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            int counter = 0;
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                Posts posts = snapshot.getValue(Posts.class);

                if (posts.getPublisher().equals(profileId)) counter ++;
            }

            post.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });

}

private void userInfo() {
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(profileId).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);
            username.setText("@" + user.getUsername());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
}
```

}
The above is the code of the profile activity

```
public class MyPosts extends Fragment {

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private PostAdapter photoAdapter;
private List<Posts> myPhotoList;

private FirebaseUser fUser;
String profileId;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my_thoughts, container, false);

    fUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    String data = getContext().getSharedPreferences("PROFILE", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
            .getString("profileId", "none");

    if (data.equals("none")){
        profileId = fUser.getUid();
    } else{
        profileId = data;
    }

    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_pictures);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 1));
    myPhotoList = new ArrayList<>();
    photoAdapter = new PostAdapter(getContext(), myPhotoList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(photoAdapter);


    myPhotos();

    return view;
}

private void myPhotos() {

    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Posts").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            myPhotoList.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                Posts post = snapshot.getValue(Posts.class);

                if (post.getPublisher().equals(profileId)){
                    myPhotoList.add(post);
                }
            }

            Collections.reverse(myPhotoList);
            photoAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });

}
```

}

the above is the code for the posts fragments inside the viewpager of the profile activity

```
public class Profile extends Fragment {

private CircleImageView imageProfile;
private TextView followers;
private TextView following;
private TextView fullname;
private TextView bio;
private CircleImageView verification;
private TextView usernamebottom;
private Button editProfile;
private FirebaseUser fUser;

String profileId;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);

    fUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    String data = getContext().getSharedPreferences("PROFILE", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
            .getString("profileId", "none");

    if (data.equals("none")){
        profileId = fUser.getUid();
    } else{
        profileId = data;
        getContext().getSharedPreferences("PROFILE", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit().clear().apply();
    }

    imageProfile = view.findViewById(R.id.image_profile);
    verification = view.findViewById(R.id.verification_profile);
    followers = view.findViewById(R.id.followers);
    following = view.findViewById(R.id.following);
    fullname = view.findViewById(R.id.full_name);
    bio = view.findViewById(R.id.bio);
    usernamebottom = view.findViewById(R.id.username_btm);
    editProfile = view.findViewById(R.id.edit_profile);

    getFollowersAndFollowingCount();
    userInfo();

    if (profileId.equals(fUser.getUid())){
        editProfile.setText("Edit profile");
    } else {
        checkFollowingStatus();
    }
    editProfile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String btnText = editProfile.getText().toString();

            if (btnText.equals("Edit profile")){
                //Go to edit profile
                startActivity(new Intent(getContext(), EditProfileActivity.class));
            } else{
                if (btnText.equals("follow")){
                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Follow").child(fUser.getUid())
                            .child("following").child(profileId).setValue(true);
                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Follow")
                            .child(profileId).child("followers").child(fUser.getUid()).setValue(true);
                } else {
                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Follow").child(fUser.getUid())
                            .child("following").child(profileId).removeValue();
                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Follow")
                            .child(profileId).child("followers").child(fUser.getUid()).removeValue();
                }
            }
        }
    });

    return view;
}

private void checkFollowingStatus() {

    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Follow").child(fUser.getUid()).child("following")
            .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if (dataSnapshot.child(profileId).exists()) {
                        editProfile.setText("following");
                    } else {
                        editProfile.setText("follow");
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                }
            });

}

private void getFollowersAndFollowingCount() {

    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Follow").child(profileId);

    ref.child("followers").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            followers.setText("" + dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });

    ref.child("following").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            following.setText("" + dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });

}

private void userInfo() {

    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(profileId).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);

            if (user.getImageurl().equals("default")){
                imageProfile.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_empty_profile);
            } else {
                Picasso.get().load(user.getImageurl()).into(imageProfile);
            }

            

            usernamebottom.setText("@" + user.getUsername());
            fullname.setText(user.getName());
            bio.setText(user.getBio());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });


}
```

}
The above is the code of the user detail fragment also in the view pager of my profile activity

Comment: I am not entirely sure I understand what you're asking. You used to save the profiles in local storage, now you want to store them in the real-time database, right? Or do you already save in DB, just want to remove the local portion?

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors? Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo My application is similar to that of Instagram /Twitter. This code actually works but not the way I want it to. While I am the logged in user in this app and when i go to my profile, it shows my details, my posts. But when I click on the username of other users from home or search and go to their profile, it still shows my profile details, and my posts not theirs.  All the user details, post details are already stored in the realtime database. But I need a way to call them instead of the shared preferences.

Comment: @AbdullahZKhan Don't mind the code that I had shared. There is nothing wrong with the code. The details of the user and his posts are saved in the realtime database. Guide me of  a way to get the user and the posts details when i go to the profile of myself or for other users in the app. If you are understand and can help I could share the entire code of the profile activity, and the three fragments in the viewpager of the profile activity.

Comment: How do you save the posts? By name, by id, by uid?

Comment: @AbdullahZKhan The images are stored in firebase storage at first and then they are stored in the realtime database with the postId, imageurl and the uid of the publisher using hashmap.